# Git Lab - Schedule MR Monthly

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can I open an MR monthly (first day of the month) automatically to merge `branch_a` with `branch_b`? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in a way.

You can use [pipeline schedules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) to trigger a pipeline job that creates a merge request between the branches using the [GitLab merge requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr).